# Conda command not recognized after adding Path (Windows 10)

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-10, conda

After following the advice described in various other similar posts of adding the necessary paths, I continue to receive the error described above in the title. Being out of trouble shooting ideas, I had started adding a number of paths hoping one of them would make the conda command accessible (these are seen in the [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgfE5.png)). Does anybody know what the problem may be, or could provide me with more resources to help me troubleshoot? All the resources I have found just suggest to add the path.

Comment: From the command prompt, what does `echo %PATH%` give you?

Comment: Thanks, yeah you're right, the path's i added manually aren't showing up when i display them in the command line with echo %PATH%. So I've been playing around a bit more and i've found that they only appear if I run the command prompt as admin. But otherwise opening the command prompt normally these added paths remain absent. I'm not sure if that is helpful info to figure out my problem, and i suppose i could technically always run the prompt in admin mode, but that seems needlessly annoying.

Comment: Be careful, you shouldn't manually edit the PATH when installing Anaconda, see the [FAQ](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/faq/).

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! For anyone that has a similar problem in the future: it seems that opening the environment variables was defaulting to editing the environment variables of the admin account instead of the user account that I was using. Therefore appending the desired directory to the user path was only changing the path for the admin user. By typing 'edit environment variables for your account' I was able to find the terminal with which I was able to change the user environment variables for my user account. Everything worked as one would expect following this change; meaning after pressing ok to close the environment editor and restarting the command prompt the added paths appeared.